# Stretch apt-get update error: 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file

Tags: raspbian, apt, update, raspbian-stretch

Cannot do first update for a straight from raspberrypi.org download of 2017-09-07-raspian-stretch image due to errors:

```
pi@RWPi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Err:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch Release
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 46.235.227.11 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch 
Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration 
details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release' 
does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration 
details.
```

(Have been chasing this on raspberrypi.org forum but no answers there.  Latest post with config info: 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=196666&e=1&view=unread#p1230124

Edit:  $ curl -4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/Release

Returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That does sound very frustrating to go from an attempted jessie-upgrade to this. As you have indicated on the forums it does appear that both your DNS and IPv4 connection are working given you can get as far as a 404. To determine if there isn't some redirector in the way, if you run `curl http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/Release`, do you also get a 404 or the actual file? Digging further up the stack, you can run `sudo apt-get update --print-uris` to see if it's somehow using the wrong URL which leads to that 404.

Comment: Thanks for providing more detail. Given your curl command gives 404 when it works for me, it's likely mirrordirector is redirecting you to a broken mirror. Can you try one of the mirrors listed on https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors ? Unfortunately many of those are broken, so first browse to confirm one that works from your location and is up-to-date.
Not sure if archive.raspberrypi.org redirects as well, but once you find a working mirror that includes `source` packages you can use `deb-src` on it. There are also other posts here on Pi Exchange dealing with mirrordirector problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this particular Pi3 may have developed a built-in WIFI problem.  It was working fine for the prior six months.  Then I had the SD card go "read-only", and now this.

I tried curl http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/raspbian/raspbian/dists/stretch/Release.

On my mac it succeeds.

On a different Raspberry Pi3 it succeeds.

On my robot Pi3 (sitting right next to my DeskPi3), it fails.

On my robot Pi3, adding an USB WIFI dongle, it configured two ip addresses, and the apt-get succeeded completely.

Comment: yes I can confirm this...the raspbian stretch version is buggy...dns faild with eth0 but plugging a wifi device do it well....