# Unable to install Firefox or Thunderbird (Icedove)

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-stretch

I have been trying to install Firefox and Thunderbird on Raspbian Stretch, but I have not been able to.

## Edit: This issue seems to have been resolved for now. For some reason the `sudo apt-get update` worked for the first time and I have not had any issue since.

When using apt-get I get the following:

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr
Suggested packages:
  fonts-stix | otf-stix fonts-lmodern mozplugger
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox-esr iceweasel
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 93.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf firefox-esr armhf 52.3.0esr-1~deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf iceweasel all 52.3.0esr-1~deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/firefox-esr/firefox-esr_52.3.0esr-1~deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/f/firefox-esr/iceweasel_52.3.0esr-1~deb9u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I have tried `sudo apt-get install iceweasel --fix-missing` and I have tried using aptitude, but the result is more or less the same.

I have the same trouble trying to install Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt-get install icedove
```

Exact same thing here as above, there is no need to repeat it.

When I run `sudo apt-get update`I get an error:

```
sudo apt-get update

Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [25.3 kB]        
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]  
Get:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [11.7 MB]
Err:3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages  
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:11654960 [weak]
   - SHA256:35b892acd1fd1d1db71f4d8b29e6bdac4e2adfdb940c96e367ed3bba5ee09afa
   - SHA1:ba6d202f28267fba982386f0a06ddb8bf65cfb20 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8e20774c77763765e73612aac43137f1 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:a51247270bf7ee4c82364fe92ec81ec3fc0baf765ffac7e2a7f3b2e361f9cfff
   - SHA1:c7e62b4b66eadb543fd0f9ea174c61b5b2c53e93 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ad7770149a28e999e207598fb66f1d1f [weak]
   - Filesize:5352930 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 22:30:00 +0000
  Release file created at: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 22:31:59 +0000
Get:4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/contrib armhf Packages [56.8 kB]
Get:5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/non-free armhf Packages [95.2 kB]
Fetched 1,378 kB in 1min 15s (18.2 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:11654960 [weak]
    - SHA256:35b892acd1fd1d1db71f4d8b29e6bdac4e2adfdb940c96e367ed3bba5ee09afa
    - SHA1:ba6d202f28267fba982386f0a06ddb8bf65cfb20 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8e20774c77763765e73612aac43137f1 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:a51247270bf7ee4c82364fe92ec81ec3fc0baf765ffac7e2a7f3b2e361f9cfff
    - SHA1:c7e62b4b66eadb543fd0f9ea174c61b5b2c53e93 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ad7770149a28e999e207598fb66f1d1f [weak]
    - Filesize:5352930 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 22:30:00 +0000
   Release file created at: Sun, 24 Dec 2017 22:31:59 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list` gives me:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

When I uncommented the last line it gave the same error on update.

My internet connection seems to be working fine, I can search and browse, and I was able to download `vlc` using apt-get and `vnstat` using aptitude.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: 404 tends to indicate DNS is working but the destination files aren't found. Last I saw that in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74706/stretch-apt-get-update-error-http-archive-raspberrypi-org-debian-stretch-rel). We troubledshooted via `--print-uris` and running `curl` commands but it was never fully rootcaused. If you'd like to examine the 404s please post some similar diagnostics. Though might fix on a working `sudo apt update`: It says your 11 MB file got truncated to 5 MB, so try wired ethernet, faster connection (tether your phone), or different mirror URL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is likely due to a network outrage and cannot be reproduced.